# Cocos2d-JS 3.0 migration

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-html5, cocos2d-js

I'm moving from cocos2d-html5 version 2.2 to cocos2d-js 3.0 and I have a problem with this code (which works perfectly in version 2.2):

```
        menuButtons = cc.Menu.create();
        for (var a = 1; a < 6; a++){

            var label = cc.LabelTTF.create("BUTTON " + a, "Arial", 20);
            var tmpBtn = cc.MenuItemLabel.create(label, function (e) {
                cc.log("TEST TAG: " + e.tag);
                //StartSomethingOther(e);
            }, this);

            tmpBtn.setPosition(50, a * 30);
            tmpBtn.tag = a;

            menuButtons.addChild(tmpBtn,2,1);

        }
        menuButtons.setPosition(10, 10);
        this.addChild(menuButtons, 1);
```

Any "button" is pressed the console always output "TEST TAG: 1" instead of putting the correct number.
Any tip to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the .tag with .title or even better a ['data-'] identifier like in this example:

```
        menuButtons = cc.Menu.create();
        for (var a = 1; a < 6; a++){

            var label = cc.LabelTTF.create("BUTTON " + a, "Arial", 20);
            var tmpBtn = cc.MenuItemLabel.create(label, function (e) {
                cc.log("TEST TAG: " + e['data-tag']);
                //StartSomethingOther(e);
            }, this);

            tmpBtn.setPosition(50, a * 30);
            tmpBtn['data-tag'] = a;

            menuButtons.addChild(tmpBtn,2,1);

        }
        menuButtons.setPosition(10, 10);
        this.addChild(menuButtons, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting `tag` property here:

```
menuButtons.addChild(tmpBtn,2,1);
```

the third parameter sets `tmpBtn.tag` to 1.

If You want to continue to use `tag` property simply change:

```
        tmpBtn.tag = a;
        menuButtons.addChild(tmpBtn,2,1);
```

with:

```
        menuButtons.addChild(tmpBtn,2,a);
```

If You don't want to use `tag` property, see [Francesco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24033304/2277211)'s answer